# How do i install particular repository from Github?

Tags: command-line, scripts, github

I'm new to ubuntu terminal and I'm trying to learn the basics.

How do I install this repository?
https://github.com/golemfactory/golem

These are the instructions from the link:

- For Ubuntu (16.04 or higher) download script,
- make it executable `chmod +x install.sh`, and
- run `./install.sh`

How do I download the script? when pressed it is redirecting me to a new tab with the written script.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, install the package git:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git
```

At the link you gave, there is a green button marked *Clone or download.* Click it and then click the clipboard icon. This will copy the git link to your clipboard. Now, back to the terminal:

```
git clone https://github.com/golemfactory/golem.git
cd golem/Installer/Installer_Linux
./install.sh
```

Comment: If this answer has been helpful, please accept it so that the searchers can see which one worked. https://askubuntu.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

You can install it as follow:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/golemfactory/golem/develop/Installer/Installer_Linux/install.sh
chmod +x install.sh
./install.sh
```

See : [Installation on Ubuntu](https://github.com/golemfactory/golem/wiki/Installation-on-Ubuntu)

> The officially supported release is 16.04 at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Now the steps would be:

1. Open your terminal with: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>
2. Type this line and press <kbd>enter</kbd>:

   ```
   wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/golemfactory/golem/develop/Installer/Installer_Linux/install.sh
   ```
3. Still in that terminal type:

   ```
   chmod +x install.sh
   ```
4. Now run the file by typing in the terminal, and providinh any password if asked:

   ```
   ./install.sh
   ```

Another way would be to type this in the terminal:

```
wget -O - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/golemfactory/golem/develop/Installer/Installer_Linux/install.sh | bash
```

But of course this is done if you want to download and run it at once and if you completely trust this script, **but download it separately and read it before running it the first time**.

Answer (score 0):

Although command line options are nice, there is a way to download only a single page from GitHub without copying links.

First open the file you have to download on GitHub on Firefox, you will see a link as "Raw" click on that. Now you will have only that file in browser. Use `Ctrl+S` or "Save page as" to save it where you want.

The  you can run `chmod +x install.sh` to make it executable.

Then use `./install.sh` to run it.